# what is the use of enableProdMode() in Angular

Tags: angular5, production-environment

I have been working on a project and there is following check in its main.ts file :

```
if (environment.production) {
   enableProdMode();
}
```

I have gone through documentation to understand this. It says :

> Disable Angular's development mode, which turns off assertions and
>   other checks within the framework.
>
> One important assertion this disables verifies that a change detection
>   pass does not result in additional changes to any bindings (also known
>   as unidirectional data flow).

But this does not ring any bell for me.

Answer (score 0):

is equivalent to `ng build --prod` will enable prod mode.

Enabling prod mode will disable some validation, speeding up your code.

Note: `--prod` Change mode for this build only, than again reset default `dev mode` )

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```